# bazel Target @platforms//os:windows was referenced as a platform, but does not provide PlatformInfo

Tags: bazel

I am beginning to use bazel 2.0

I am building with visual studio 2015

I  have a `cc_library` with deps using select ":windows" and ":linux"

windows and linux were defined as follow

```
config_setting(
  name = "windows",
  constraint_values = ["@platforms//os:windows"]
)
config_setting(
  name = "linux",
  constraint_values = ["@platforms//os:linux"]
)
```

bazel build base was working (generating the lib)

unfortunately I need to differentiate under windows between 32 bits and 64 bits since I need those target to be built under 32 and 64 bits

I changed "windows" to "windows_x86_64" defined as follow

```
config_setting(
  name = "windows_x86_64", 
  values = {
    "cpu": "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    "platforms": "@platforms//os:windows",
  },
)
```

```
bazel build base \
  --platforms=@platforms//os:windows \
  --cpu=@platforms//cpu:x86_66 \
  --incompatible_use_platforms_repo_for_constraints
```

gives me the following error message

> ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target //lib/base:windows_x86_64: Target @platforms//os:windows was referenced as a platform, but does not provide PlatformInfo
> ERROR: Analysis of target '//lib/base:base' failed; build aborted: Target @platforms//os:windows was referenced as a platform, but does not provide PlatformInfo

I know I am missing something. I cannot figure out what. I searched what could be this PlatformInfo and how to retrieve it, unsuccessfully.

Any help, pointer appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat confusingly `@platforms//...` doesn't actually have any platforms defined in it, instead, it has a set of constraint_values that you can use to create a platform.

e.g.

```py
# BUILD.bazel
platform(
    name = "windows_x86_32",
    constraint_values = [
       "@platforms//cpu:x86_32",
       "@platforms//os:windows",
    ],
)

platform(
    name = "windows_x86_64",
    constraint_values = [
       "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
       "@platforms//os:windows",
    ],
)

# The rest of your build file...
```

You should then be able to build using the command;

```
bazel build base --platforms=//:windows_x86_32
# or 
bazel build base --platforms=//:windows_x86_64
```

Comment: That is incredibly confusing indeed. Is there a way to set a platform automatically based on the target? E.g. with `ios_application`.

Comment: It's possible using [user defined transitions](https://bazel.build/extending/config#user-defined-transitions) but its far from trivial. e.g. you can create a platform as above and then create a transition on the `//command_line_option:platform` [native options](https://bazel.build/extending/config#transitions-native-options). Hopefully that gets you started. There are a few examples of this in the rules_docker repository. I can't really comment on ios specific stuff as I don't own a mac or ios device.